# Get returned value from function in condition in Ion Auth

Tags: php, ion-auth

In the auth/create_user function, there is the following code:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data)) {
```

This is when the new user is being created.  the $this->ion_auth->register function returns the newly created user's id.  My question is, how do I access that user id?  It's not assigned to a variable, and I'm not sure how to access it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign it to a variable:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true &&
   ($id = $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data)))
{
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Wasn't sure I could assign the $id var there and have the condition still work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Abra's answer is wrong... You wont get the id from the register method, it would only return True or False.

Try using CI's `$this->db->insert_id()` to get the ID of the last inserted user into the table

Comment: You can downvote if an answer is incorrect, I don't really think it belongs to your answer.

Comment: the author said he want's the newly created user's id, and i only said a solution that he could try